# How animate the imageView across the layout on android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I trying to animate the ImageView from child layout(Relativelayout) to parent layout(Relative layout). the imageview is not getting painted while entering into the parent layout.

```
enter code 




/** Called when the activity is first created. */

private static final int   SWIPE_MIN          = 20;
private static final int   SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
private static final int   SWIPE_THRESHOLD    = 20;
GestureDetector detector;
ImageView topImage;
ImageView bottomImage;
ImageView aView;
RelativeLayout rlBottomChild;
RelativeLayout rlTopChild;
FrameLayout flTopChild;
FrameLayout flBottomChild;
RelativeLayout table;
RelativeLayout relativeLayout ;
FrameLayout frameLayout ;
WindowManager wManger;
int screenWidth;
int screenHeight;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    wManger = getWindowManager();
    screenWidth = wManger.getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
    screenHeight = wManger.getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
    detector = new GestureDetector(this);

    bottomImage = new ImageView(this);
    bottomImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);
    bottomImage.setOnTouchListener(this);
    bottomImage.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

    topImage = new ImageView(this);
    topImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);
    topImage.setOnTouchListener(this);
    topImage.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);


    initRelativeLayout();


    setContentView(relativeLayout);
}


/**
 * <p> Used to </p>
 */
private void initRelativeLayout() {



    // Top Player 
    rlTopChild = new RelativeLayout(this);
    rlTopChild.setId(1);
    LayoutParams p2 = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT  , ((10*screenHeight)/100));
    p2.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
    rlTopChild.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    rlTopChild.addView(topImage);
    rlTopChild.setLayoutParams(p2);

    // Bottom Player 
    rlBottomChild = new RelativeLayout(this);
    rlBottomChild.setId(3);
    LayoutParams p = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT  , ((10*screenHeight)/100));
    p.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
    rlBottomChild.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    rlBottomChild.addView(bottomImage);
    rlBottomChild.setClipChildren(false);
    rlBottomChild.setLayoutParams(p);


    // Table Layout 
    table = new RelativeLayout(this);
    table.setId(2);
    LayoutParams p3 = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT  , ((50*screenHeight)/100));
    p3.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
    p3.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW , rlTopChild.getId());
    p3.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE , rlBottomChild.getId());
    table.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    table.setLayoutParams(p3);


    relativeLayout =new RelativeLayout(this);
    relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    relativeLayout.addView(rlBottomChild);
    relativeLayout.addView(rlTopChild);
    relativeLayout.addView(table);
}

/**
 * <p> Overriding the method </p>
 * @param v
 * @param event
 * @return
 * @see android.view.View.OnTouchListener#onTouch(android.view.View, android.view.MotionEvent)
 */
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    return  detector.onTouchEvent(event);

}

/**
 * <p> Overriding the method </p>
 * @param e
 * @return
 * @see android.view.GestureDetector.OnGestureListener#onDown(android.view.MotionEvent)
 */
@Override
public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
    // TODOAuto-generated method stub
    return true;

}

/**
 * <p> Overriding the method </p>
 * @param e1
 * @param e2
 * @param velocityX
 * @param velocityY
 * @return
 * @see android.view.GestureDetector.OnGestureListener#onFling(android.view.MotionEvent, android.view.MotionEvent, float, float)
 */
@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
    try {
        if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH){
            return false;
        }
        if (e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD) {
           debug("Left Swipe");
           TranslateAnimation animation= new TranslateAnimation(e1.getX(),e2.getX(),e1.getY() ,e2.getY());
           animation.setAnimationListener(this);
           animation.setDuration(3000);
           bottomImage.startAnimation(animation);
        } else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD) {
            debug("Right Swipe ");
            debug("Swipe down ...");
            TranslateAnimation animation= new TranslateAnimation(e1.getX(),e2.getX(),e1.getY() ,e2.getY());
            animation.setAnimationListener(this);
            animation.setDuration(3000);
            topImage.startAnimation(animation);
        } else if (e1.getY() - e2.getY() > SWIPE_MIN && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD) {
           debug("Swipe up ... ");
           TranslateAnimation animation= new TranslateAnimation(e1.getX(),e2.getX(),e1.getY() ,e2.getY());
           animation.setAnimationListener(this);
           animation.setDuration(3000);
           bottomImage.startAnimation(animation);
        } else if (e2.getY() - e1.getY() > SWIPE_MIN && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD) {
            debug("Swipe down ...");
            TranslateAnimation animation= new TranslateAnimation(e1.getX(),e2.getX(),e1.getY() ,e2.getY());
            animation.setAnimationListener(this);
            animation.setDuration(3000);
            topImage.startAnimation(animation);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // nothing
    }
    return true;

}

/**
 * <p> Used to </p>
 * @param string
 */
private void debug(String string) {
    Log.d("TAGGG", string);         
}

/**
 * <p> Overriding the method </p>
 * @param e
 * @see android.view.GestureDetector.OnGestureListener#onLongPress(android.view.MotionEvent)
 */
@Override
public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
    // TODOAuto-generated method stub

}

/**
 * <p> Overriding the method </p>
 * @param e1
 * @param e2
 * @param distanceX
 * @param distanceY
 * @return
 * @see android.view.GestureDetector.OnGestureListener#onScroll(android.view.MotionEvent, android.view.MotionEvent, float, float)
 */
@Override
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
    // TODOAuto-generated method stub
    return true;

}

/**
 * <p> Overriding the method </p>
 * @param e
 * @see android.view.GestureDetector.OnGestureListener#onShowPress(android.view.MotionEvent)
 */
@Override
public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {
    // TODOAuto-generated method stub

}

/**
 * <p> Overriding the method </p>
 * @param e
 * @return
 * @see android.view.GestureDetector.OnGestureListener#onSingleTapUp(android.view.MotionEvent)
 */
@Override
public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
    // TODOAuto-generated method stub
    return true;

}

/**
 * <p> Overriding the method </p>
 * @param animation
 * @see android.view.animation.Animation.AnimationListener#onAnimationEnd(android.view.animation.Animation)
 */
@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
    // TODOAuto-generated method stub

}

/**
 * <p> Overriding the method </p>
 * @param animation
 * @see android.view.animation.Animation.AnimationListener#onAnimationRepeat(android.view.animation.Animation)
 */
@Override
public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
    // TODOAuto-generated method stub

}

/**
 * <p> Overriding the method </p>
 * @param animation
 * @see android.view.animation.Animation.AnimationListener#onAnimationStart(android.view.animation.Animation)
 */
@Override
public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
}
```

}

here

Thanks. 
jega

Comment: Hey Jega, can you post a little more context? I am actually confused by the code as I don't know where the translation dx/dy are coming from. Does the animation listener remove the ImageView from it's original position and then add it to the other layout? Does it add the appropriate Rules to the ImageView's LayoutPArams in order to properly align it?

Comment: Thx Greg , Animation listener will not remove the child. i have updated my code. can you please help me.

Answer (score 5):

In order to draw a View outside its parent you need to set clipChildren to false in the parent View.

Add the following lines in your code and it should now work:

```
relativeLayout.setClipChildren(false);
rlBottomChild.setClipChildren(false);
rlTopChild.setClipChildren(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Android offers a custom 2D graphics library for drawing and animating shapes and images. The android.graphics.drawable and android.view.animation packages are where you'll find the common classes used for drawing and animating in two-dimensions.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html

Answer (score 0):

For changes caused by animations to persist in Android you need to add this line:

```
animation.setFillAfter(true);
```